# Q: Will deleting index on Mongodb create locking?

Tags: mongodb

I been planning to delete index on Primary, and just creating them on the Replica Set. not sure yet if this works. some say they do. but I want to delete index on a collection. not sure if it will create locking and prevent new inserts?

Answer (score 1):

Droping indexes will obtain a write lock on the affected database and will block other operation until it's finished. Check documentation here -

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dropIndexes/

Comment: even if its a background index?

Comment: The elephant in the room is why does it lock? "Boggle*